# Double pointer to Xamarin.iOS NSMutableArray becomes null in Objective C layer

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I am trying to pass a reference of an NSMutableArray from Xamarin.iOS which becomes null in Objective C layer.

Xamarin.iOS  application

```
NSMutableArray arraySample = new NSMutableArray();  
IntPtr availableHandle = arraySample.Handle;  
var result = SampleLibrary.MutableArrayTest(out arraySample);
```

Objective C static library

```
+(NSMutableArray *)arrayReturningTesting:(NSMutableArray **)prameterArray
{
    if ((prameterArray == nil) || (*prameterArray == nil))
    {
          NSLog(@"prameterArray is null");
          return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray *arrayNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"11", @"12", nil];
    NSMutableArray *finalArray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arrayNumbers addObjectsFromArray:*prameterArray];
    [finalArray addObjectsFromArray:arrayNumbers];
    NSLog(@"prameterArray is not null");

    return finalArray;
}
```

Output : prameterArray is null
Expected output : prameterArray is not null

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Pass it as `ref` (changing your C# API wrapper to match of course)

Comment: @SushiHangover ,thanks for the reply . but still prameterArray is null

Comment: Update your question with your current code, including your C# API wrapper

Comment: [Export("arrayReturningTesting:")]
        NSMutableArray ArrayReturningTesting(ref NSMutableArray returnValue);